# Set #Wordpress Permalink with PHP with Conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, code-snippets

What im trying to accomplish is set different wordpress permalink for logged in users
For logged in users use: `/loggedin/%post_id%/%postname%/` and for others use `/post/%post_id%/%postname%/`

Here is the PHP code which Im trying but not working

```
add_action( 'init', 'smartest_set_permalinks' );
function smartest_set_permalinks() {
global $wp_rewrite;
if(is_user_logged_in) {
$wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/loggedin/%post_id%/%postname%/' );
} else {
$wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/post/%post_id%/%postname%/' );
}};
```

What am i missing here can somebody point out or fix this?

Comment: What kind of 'not working'? Is it just not working or throwing some error?

Comment: Not working, it was always using /logged/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the '()' after is_user_logged_in. is_user_logged_in() is a default wordpress function. And the semicolon in the end of function brace is not needed.

```
add_action( 'init', 'smartest_set_permalinks' );
function smartest_set_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/loggedin/%post_id%/%postname%/' );
    } else {
        $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/post/%post_id%/%postname%/' );
    }
}
```